# Is "The mother is asking her son 'Does your hand hurt?' grammatical?

Tags: tense, definite-article, questions, reported-speech

> The mother is asking her son ‘Does your hand hurt?’

The sentence is about a picture in which a mother is talking to her son and he is injured. Is the structure and punctuation of the sentence OK?

Can we say 'Is your hand hurting?' instead of 'Does you hand hurt?' Is there any difference?

And do I have to use 'the' before mother?

Comment: About dropping *the* - are you asking about grammatical correctness, or are you talking about preserving the meaning? If you drop *the* before *mother*, it sounds like you're talking about *your* mother, and *her* in "her son" refers to someone else (not your mother).

Comment: I'm asking about grammatical correctness.I think it sounds incorrect to say 'the mother', but I don't know why. Logically it must be Ok. This sentence is about a picture in which a mother is talking to her son and he is injured.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your question's tag and your comment in response to my query above indicate that you are focusing on grammar rather than meaning.

---

Yes, grammatically, the definite article ("The") is fine before "mother". You can place determiners before any noun (at most one determiner per noun).

Here's a guideline regarding "the":

> We use the definite article in front of a noun when we believe the hearer/reader knows exactly what we are referring to.
>   [- British Council](https://learnenglish.britishcouncil.org/en/english-grammar/determiners-and-quantifiers/definite-article)

Grammatically, both your simple present and the continuous forms are fine. They are clearly different grammatically (the tenses are different), but the meaning conveyed in each case is effectively identical.

Again, *grammatically*, there is no need to use *the* before *mother*. However, the meaning will change. Saying "the mother" refers to someone that the context has identified, most likely not the speaker's mother. Dropping the definite article changes the reference to your own mother or (depending on culture) possibly the hearer's mother.